# It is possible to 'Set-Cookie's for every request received in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: http, cookies, request, ruby-on-rails-3, set

I would like to load cookies everytime and everywhere in my website because when my RoR application receives and accepts an "external" HTTP request (ex: REST API), cookies are not loaded (see [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)). So their values are inaccessible.

Cookies are accessible only when the HTTP request is made "internally" in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST APIs are generally stateless, therefore you should avoid the use of server-side sessions or client-side cookies. If you want to indicate that a user only grabs resources belonging to them, use the Rails nested resources approach, that results in a call like:

```
http://abc.com/user/user001/books
```

For all books that belong to user001.

If you are looking to implement security, first you have to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. For the actual implementation you can use Basic Authentication and set the username/password in the request header or you can use something like OAuth which sets up a token for the user that they pass in with each request.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_cookies = {"Cookie" => "mycookie=1234;myothercookie=4567"}
Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( http: //app1.website.com/users ),  new_cookies)
```

Comment: I think it is unsafe to send cookies data (in my case the current_user_id) via an HTTP GET requests because there may be a"Man in the middle" attack. What do you think about?

Comment: The original request from your user's browser was an HTTP GET right? That is more likely to be intercepted than a request to another server in your own subnet. You could of course encrypt the value or use https.

Comment: Are you using this approach? And do you advise me to use it? Maybe, to avoid this data flow and related issues, there is a better (unknown to me) solution to load cookies everytime and everywhere. I can not believe, for example, to use this approach to implement REST APIs if I have to pass always the cookie values with a GET request to check the current user sign in.

Comment: You probably do not want to rely on cookies if you are implementing a REST API. Using cookies is no more secure than sending the user id in a request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers will automatically send any cookies you set from your domain, you can check them simply by calling `request.cookies` from any controller method. It doesn't matter if the request was initiated from within your application (such as a 302 redirect) or not.

Comment: I did that and I received a blank hash. Maybe do I have to set something in application.rb, enviroment.rb, ...?

Comment: If you are using Firefox I'd recommend installing Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) and Firecookie (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683/) and making sure those cookies you are looking for are actually being set in the browser.

Comment: I already did also this. It is all right with cookies: they exist.

Comment: So you are saying that your browser has a cookie, X for your domain xyz.com, and when you enter xyz.com/controller/action1 in your browser you see no cookies, but when you enter xyz.com/controller/action2 and that does a redirect to xyz.com/controller/action1 you do see the cookies?

Comment: What I am trying to understand is what you mean by an internal request?

Comment: Real example - I have 2 RoR applications: app1.website.com and app2.website.com. If I make a GET HTTP request from app1 to app2 (or vice versa) the cookies in app2 are not accessible (and viceversa), but they are accessible if I do a GET HTTP request from app1 to app1 (and from app2 to app2).

Comment: Sibling sub domains cannot share cookies, if you want them to share a cookie make sure the domain value for that cookie is a parent domain (website.com) when you set it.

Comment: Sibling, I did that for both app1 and app2 in session_store.rb with this: cookies.signed[:current_user_id] = { :value => [user.id,
user.make_user_id_salt(user.id)], :expires =>
15.days.from_now, :domain => ".website.com" }

Comment: Why is there a dot in front of the website.com domain? Did you verify in firecookie that the domain was set to website.com and not app1.website.com?

Comment: I just tryed both cases (with and without ".") and also restarted the server, but nothing yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this with Firecookie:

1. Created a cookie "mycoolcookie" for the domain ".stackoverflow.com"
2. Went to stackoverflow.com, firebug showed that the cookie was sent in the request header.
3. Went to meta.stackoverflow.com, firebug showed that the cookie was sent in the request header.
4. Went to chat.stackoverflow.com, firebug showed that the cookie was sent in the request header.

A cookie is sent automatically by the browser, the server can never request for a cookie to be sent to it.

Comment: I tryed to use a simple GET HTTP request "Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( 'http: //app1.website.com/users' ) )" from the app2 to the app1 and in the 'app1/controllers/users_controllers.rb' the cookie are not followed (they are not present in the request header). Is it possible that I do not set properly some configuration option?

Comment: You are creating a brand new request from the server, which is now acting like a new client. You have to manually set the cookie in the request header. Check out the example below.

Comment: Is it possible not acting like a new client? If so, how?

Comment: No, but by copying all the cookies that came from your original client's request to the new request (HTTP.get) then for all purposes it is the same user.

Comment: Are you sure? Cookies, within a domain, should not be accessible "internally" from that domain also if a request was made from outside?